# Multiple libraries were found for "WiFiClient.h" using nodemcu

Tags: arduino-ide, nodemcu

I am trying to send HTTP requests from nodemcu so I started by uploading the esp8266 library but when I run the following code

```
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);                                  //Serial connection
  WiFi.begin("Iphone de elaa", "27343550");   //WiFi connection

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {  //Wait for the WiFI connection completion

    delay(500);
    Serial.println("Waiting for connection");

  }

}

void loop() {

 if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){   //Check WiFi connection status

   HTTPClient http;    //Declare object of class HTTPClient

   http.begin("http://localhost:8080/getallcadres/getnbpassage/5");      //Specify request destination
   http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");  //Specify content-type header

   int httpCode = http.POST("5");   //Send the request
   String payload = http.getString();                  //Get the response payload

   Serial.println(httpCode);   //Print HTTP return code
   Serial.println(payload);    //Print request response payload

   http.end();  //Close connection

 }else{

    Serial.println("Error in WiFi connection");   

 }

  delay(30000);  //Send a request every 30 seconds

}
```

i got this error

```
Arduino: 1.8.9 (Windows Store 1.8.21.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Generic ESP8266 Module, 80 MHz, Flash, Disabled, All SSL ciphers (most compatible), ck, 26 MHz, 40MHz, DOUT (compatible), 512K (no SPIFFS), 2, nonos-sdk 2.2.1 (legacy), v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

Build options changed, rebuilding all
In file included from C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiClientSecure.h:41:0,

                 from C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiServerSecure.h:20,

                 from C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/ESP8266WiFi.h:41,

                 from C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\Desktop\PFE_ING\nodemcu\nodemcu.ino:2:

C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.h:38:5: error: 'BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure::~WiFiClientSecure()' marked override, but does not override

     ~WiFiClientSecure() override;

     ^

C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.h:41:9: error: 'int BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure::connect(const String&, uint16_t)' marked override, but does not override

     int connect(const String& host, uint16_t port) override;

         ^

C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.h:46:12: error: 'size_t BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure::write_P(const char*, size_t)' marked override, but does not override

     size_t write_P(PGM_P buf, size_t size) override;

            ^

C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.h:58:12: error: 'size_t BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure::peekBytes(uint8_t*, size_t)' marked override, but does not override

     size_t peekBytes(uint8_t *buffer, size_t length) override;

            ^

Multiple libraries were found for "WiFiClient.h"
 Used: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.21.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\libraries\WiFi
 Not used: C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Generic ESP8266 Module.
```

so what is this error why i am getting it 
**Edit**
i switched to an other version of arduino ide 1.6.5 the error is gone but it looks like it is not connection i got 
[image: here]

Comment: delete folder `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.21.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\libraries\WiFi`. it is the WiFi library for the retired Arduino WiFi Shield

Comment: i could not acces to windowsApps

Comment: @Juraj please check my update

Comment: better answer to this question https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=623460.msg4223849#msg4223849

Comment: relevant issue.  UPVOTED

Answer (score 6):

Simply Switch

```
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
```

to

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
```

Comment: really?  that simple?  will test to see if i can reproduce issue on ubuntu as well.  tks!!

Answer (score 0):

I am new to nodemcu. When I was using ESP8266WiFi.h, I got the error "Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module)" which said that Multiple libraries were found for ESP8266WiFi.h. I solved by simply put the void loop(){} empty function at the end of my code. Now It's working...